# Convert an AngularJS app to GWT (MVP)

Tags: angularjs, gwt, gwt-mvp

I need to convert the following [AngularJS application](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit-frontend) to a GWT application (though the question applies to any angular application). I would like to use the [MVC pattern](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html) and [UiBinder](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture-2.html) as suggested in the documentation but I'm unsure as to how the components of the angular application should correspond to the GWT one.

I've given it some thought already and here's my understanding - I'd be grateful if someone could say if I've got it right

1. Each module should become a presenter
2. One view per presenter
3. Services must be initialised in the *AppController* and passed to the relevant presenters (similarly to how an *eventBus* is implemented in the [MVC description](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/mvp-architecture.html))

Now I don't know how to put multiple presenters together, though, so that they create one page. Should I create a *main* view that would correspond to the *AppController* and then pass the relevant parts of that view to each presenter?

Also, what's the best way to handle modal dialogs? Should I just include them in the view, bind to the presenter and keep them hidden initially?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use either [Activities and Places](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html) or a fully fledged MVP framework like [GWTP](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP).

Regarding your questions:

1. I think that's right
2. One view per presenter is the usual approach. However you can also think of implementing different views for different devices (Desktop, Mobile, etc).
3. I would recommend to use a dependency injection framework like [GIN](https://code.google.com/p/google-gin/) to inject services and components into your `Presenters`

It depends if you use `Activities and Places` or `GWTP`. `GWTP` has the conecept of `PresenterWidget` that can be nested in `Presenters`. For `Activities and Places` you can follow Thomas Broyer's [recommendation](http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-activities-nesting-yagni/).

In general I think `Presenters` and their corresponding `Views` should be standalone components that are usually associated with a `Place`. `GWTP` has the concept of `Slots` (i.e. side navigation, etc) where `Presenters` can reveal themselves.

Communication between `Presenters` should be done via the `EventBus`. 
`GWTP` has a concept of `PopupPresenters` but typically I think modal dialogs should be included in the `View` and handled by the parent `Presenter` (unless it contains a lot of business logic).

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> Each module should become a presenter

look at [GWT Organize Projects][1]http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html
It talks about modules in the section, "Modules: Units of Configuration"
Basically, a module is just for configuration. You need a module for each entry point. People often have 1 module per page.

You said:

> One view per presenter

**This is usually the case.**

You said:

> Services must be initialized in the AppController and passed to the relevant presenters (similarly to how an eventBus is implemented in the MVC description)

**Like Ümit said you should use Gin**

Ümit recommended GWTP I'm no expert on GWTP but I used it briefly when I was a beginner and it was hard. I don't think it's good for beginners. Admittedly, it might be worth the investment of learning it. Like I said I'm no expert on GWTP.